# How to put breakpoints and debug Cloudflare Workers?

Tags: cloudflare-workers

How do I put breakpoints and debug Cloudflare Workers? I've read the [Cloudflare "Debugging Workers" guide](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/debugging-workers/), and unfortunately, it is not helpful.

It does mention:

> Inserting **console.log lines throughout your code** can help you understand the state of your application in various stages until you reach the desired output.

I am wondering if anyone has figured out how to debug the application more thoroughly **instead of** `console.log`, or a workaround to do this.

Thanks

One idea I had was to use a different service (GCP/Firebase cloud functions as a separate runtime / entrypoint which allows me to debug during development, which then helps. However, the Cloudflare environment is more restricted than your average cloud function/lambda (for performance reasons?). Might still be worth doing though.

Answer (score 4):

At present (March 2022), breakpoints are not yet supported by Cloudflare Workers. We'd like to support them eventually.

When breakpoints are supported, you'll be able to set them through the devtools UI, which appears when viewing a Worker through the preview UI.

Comment: Nice to hear that breakpoints are possible.

Comment: Has there been any update since the last comment?

Comment: @woj.sierak it's worth tracking this Github issue for updates: https://github.com/cloudflare/wrangler2/issues/573. It's also worth noting that running your worker in Miniflare will allow you to place breakpoints.